# How to create a 2D Cylinder using Arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, rectangles

I am trying to create different geometries in MATLAB but I am struggling to create some shapes. I thought if I made a circle, I could just stack them and create a cylinder. However, I realized that won't give me the side view of the cylinder that I want and therefore I need to create a rectangle.

Because the image I am making is binary, I believe I should use some create an array of ones. However, I am not getting the rectangular image I want.

I am also very new to MatLab and using arrays in general. Could anyone please guide me how to create a rectangle in MATLAB?

Below is an example of an attempt:

```
X = zeros(5,2);
rectanglePixels = X <= 1;
image(rectanglePixels) ;
colormap([0 0 0; 1 1 1]);
```

## UPDATE

I am closer to what I want to do, but I would like to know how to write my code cleaner.

```
a = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
rectanglePixels = a <= 0;
image(rectanglePixels) ;
colormap([1 1 1; 0 0 0]);
```

The Binary Image of Rectangle:

[image: Binary Image of Rectangle]

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
rectanglePixels = true(5,8);
rectanglePixels(2:4,4:5) = false;
image(rectanglePixels);
colormap([1 1 1; 0 0 0]);
```